# Server gzip compression vs gzipped sitemap

Tags: seo, search-engines, sitemap, gzip

My client's SEO guy said that search engines prefer gzipped sitemaps. They keep their sitemap in `.xml.gz` file.

I was wondering if there is any difference for search engines between a gzipped "on-the-fly" sitemap (i.e. by Apache or Nginx) and a "manually" gzipped file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between the two ways you describe of gzipping a *sitemap.xml* for search engines.

The important thing is to just make sure your *sitemap.xml* is gzipped, to save bandwidth for website servers and search engines, even more if your *sitemap.xml* file size is big.